# bash script strip string matching pattern

Tags: bash, sed

In a script I have I'm piping a line from the dmesg system log. On certain distros the lines are logged with the timestamp in front of each line as well.

Take this output for example:

```
[   12.291091] BTRFS info (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
```

On some distros the [] timestamp appears, while on other it's only:

```
BTRFS info (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
```

Can someone please let me know a quick way to handle the removal of the [ time ] part and display that line without it? 
The tricky part I have is that on some distros it's not there, so I'm not sure how to handle that.
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for the quick replies. Both of them answered my problem and learned me how to understand this, always having troubles with sed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sed command does what you want:

```
sed 's/^\[[^]]*] *//'
```

It matches a `[` at the start of the line, followed by any number of characters that aren't a `]`, followed by any number of spaces.

You could also do something similar using grep with Perl-style regular expressions enabled:

```
grep -Po '^(\[[^]]*] *)?\K.*'
```

The `?` means that the first part of the match is optional. This uses `\K` to remove the beginning of the match, if it exists.

Testing it out:

```
$ cat file
[ 12.291091] BTRFS info (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
BTRFS info (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
$ sed 's/^\[[^]]*] *//' file
BTRFS info (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
BTRFS info (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
$ grep -Po '^(\[[^]]*] *)?\K.*' file
BTRFS info (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
BTRFS info (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try the below sed command. It works whether the first `[]` is present or not.

```
$ echo '[   12.291091] BTRFS info (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled' | sed 's/^\[[^]]*\] *//'
BTRFS info (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
$ echo 'BTRFS info (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled' | sed 's/^\[[^]]*\] *//'
BTRFS info (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
sed -E 's/^[ \t]*\[[^]]*\][ \t]*//'
```

- will remove any spaces/tabs at the beginning of the line
- optional `[....]`
- any spaces after the `[...]`

some `sed` need the `-E` for interpeting `\t` as `<tab>`

To grep only lines containing `BTRFS` directly from the log:

```
grep -oP '\A(\s*\[[^]]*\])?\s*\K(?=BTRFS).*' <<EOF
    [   12.291091] BTRFS [info] (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
[   12.291091] BTRFS [info] (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
BTRFS [info] (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
EOF
```

prints

```
BTRFS [info] (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
BTRFS [info] (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
BTRFS [info] (device sda2): disk space caching is enabled
```